# Flash CS5 not responding when saving

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action, flash-cs5

I have a project that is getting pretty large. Large meaning lots of library assets and a pretty complicated folder structure in the library. The FLA file itself is 3,700kb and exporting a 630kb SWF …not too big. I’ve done much larger.

Starting yesterday when I save the FLA, the saving dialog appears and then I get a not responding on the dialog and I have to ctrl-alt-delete out of the flash. It happened at least 5 times yesterday over the day. It doesn't do it every time, but after I first open it, it gets progressively slower at saving then the not responding occurs.

I googled around and there’s a big thread on the adobe forum about it, but no real solution. People say its fixed in CS5 .5 but that isn’t an option for me. Has anyone experienced this or have a solution?

Comment: Defrag HDD? Have enough room on the HDD?

Comment: no thats not it. Here is the thread about it on adobe forums http://forums.adobe.com/message/3384479

Comment: That does not mean your issue is the same issue. As such thats why my answer is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced this before and have tracked it down to a corrupt image in my library. First, try a Save & Compact.

If Flash crashes during this process, or if it still doesn't work when you do a regular save, go through your library and click on the images one at a time with the library preview open. One of the items in the library should cause Flash to freeze up, and that is your problem image.

Reopen Flash, hide the preview window of the library, and then delete the offending file. Try a regular save now. If it still crashes repeat the step above with the remaining images to find more corrupt ones. Hopefully this works for you, your milage may vary.

Comment: ya know I read that somewhere..good call. My boss also had a copy of CS5.5 that he never used so I installed that and so far so good. I'm still going to go through the library and see if I can find a bad image